# How can i update recyclerView automatically when new data is inserted in MySQL database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

**How can i update recyclerView automatically when new data is inserted in MySQL database ?**

So for example like in instant chat apps like ***WhatsApp*** .By the way i don't want
to use Firebase , and i don't want to bring the whole data again.
So is that possible with MySQL database , i know it's a stupid question but i'm just a beginner .

Answer (score 0):

Try this method on the recyclerview once you have queried for new data [Recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())